# How to click a button on a webpage which does not have an ID

Tags: java, c#, html, angularjs

I am having trouble with figuring out how to click a button on a website.
The buttons code is

```
<button ng-click="form.submit(false, frm, buyQuery, ['call'])" 
        ng-mouseleave="hideDir()" ng-mouseover="showDir('call')" 
        ng-disabled="disabledControls.buyBtn">

  <i ng-class="{'mr0':chartHeight <= smallH.smallBuyBtns}"></i>

  <span ng-show="chartHeight > smallH.smallBuyBtns">Call</span>

</button>
```

I also ran into something like this but not the same before and I managed to click it with the code

```
Set form = webbrowser.Document.Body.GetElementsByTagName("form")(0)

Set button = form.GetElementsByTagName("button")(0)


button.click
```

I'm sorry my question is probably badly put but I am new to coding, If any additional info is required to answer my question please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

What's the conditions for the click event? Is it some other action?

Anyway in that part of the code where you detect that your form submit button should be clicked, just use the same code as it is in ng-click: `$scope.form.submit(false, frm, buyQuery, ['call'])`

That will work if `form` is the name of your form.

Comment: sorry I don,t fully understand what you mean by condition for the click event.

Comment: Set form = webbrowser.Document.Body.GetElementsByTagName("form")(0)
Set button = form.GetElementsByTagName("button")(0)    
button.click                                                                                                       does not  work and that is my exact code copy and pasted and the error message I get is something about the line : form.GetElementsByTagName("button")(0)